# How to pass content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" with rest assured

Tags: rest, api, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am trying to hit API using Rest assured which is a POST request with form param client id, user and password. and multiple header .

I am getting 415, unsupportted media type error. My code is:

```
Response res =    
given().
        .header("Accept", "application/json")

        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .header("channel","")
        .formParam("grant_type", "password")
        .formParam("client_id", "")
        .formParam("secret", "")
        .formParam("userId", "")
        .formParam("password","").

        when()
            .post("/apiname");
            System.out.println(res.body().asString());
```

Return type is json.

Same thing is working on PostMan. Please help in this.

Answer (score 0):

There is property in request specification for configuring the content type. Not sure that if we have to explicitly define it but i'm using the below given syntax.

```
given()
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .header("channel","")
            .formParam("grant_type", "password")
            .formParam("client_id", "")
            .formParam("secret", "")
            .formParam("userId", "")
            .formParam("password","").
                    when()
            .post("/apiname");
```